# Оффлайн доки для svg и работы на js с canvas

Tags: svg, canvas, javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где можно найти доки на английском или русском языке.

Answer (score 2):

[Дока](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Canvas_tutorial) по canvas и полезная [шпаргалочка](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas_sheet/HTML5_Canvas_Cheat_Sheet.png). Этого будет вполне достаточно. Почитайте ещё про [оптимизацию](http://habrahabr.ru/post/127014/). И есть интересная [книжечка](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920013327.do).

Comment: спасибо конечно. я я иммел ввиду оффлайн доки.

Answer (score 0):

По SVG есть исчерпывающая [подборка литературы](http://y3x.ru/2012/09/svg-books/). Все это можно взять в оффлайн.